# Broadcasting minus in tensor in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Pardon me for possibly an easy question.

Is there an elegant, numpy way to apply broadcasting minus in tensor?

e.g.

```
import numpy as np
u = np.concatenate((np.ones((3, 1)), np.zeros((3,1))), axis=1).reshape(3,1,2)
v = np.concatenate((np.zeros((3, 1)), np.ones((3,1))), axis=1).reshape(3,1,2)
```

I'll have the result

```
array([[[1, 0]],

       [[1, 0]],

       [[1, 0]]])

array([[[0, 1]],

       [[0, 1]],

       [[0, 1]]])
```

I want to know if there an elegant way to broadcasting minus. That means if I got the tensor u with shape [L, m, n] and tensor v with shape [L, m, n], and I want the result with shape [L, L, m, n], whose each second axis is the minus between the corresponding row in u and every element in v.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you want:

```
w = u.reshape(3,1,1,2) - v.reshape(1,3,1,2)
```

`w` will indeed have the desired shape of `(3, 3, 1, 2)`, and the value:

```
array([[[[ 1., -1.]],

        [[ 1., -1.]],

        [[ 1., -1.]]],


       [[[ 1., -1.]],

        [[ 1., -1.]],

        [[ 1., -1.]]],


       [[[ 1., -1.]],

        [[ 1., -1.]],

        [[ 1., -1.]]]])
```

Using `reshape` requires you to know/lookup the shape of `u` and `v`. There's an alternative (somewhat more confusing looking) syntax that will perform the same reshape/broadcasting without the explicit shape:

```
w = u[:,None,...] - v[None,...]
```

Comment: Wonderful! That's really what I want. Thanks a lot.